# SwiftData passing @Model objects as parameters in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I am trying to work with multiple views in a SwiftData based SwiftUI project. However, when I create a parameter for a SwiftData @Model object in another view, when I create a sample of that object in the #Preview, the compiler starts complaining about not implementing protocols in the @Model object.

Xcode 15 beta 2

I started with a new SwiftData project for iOS. I updated ContentView like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    @State private var selection: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            DetailView(selection: selection)
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}
```

and then I created DetailView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct DetailView: View {
    var selection: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let item = selection {
            Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
        } else {
            Text("nothing selected")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    return DetailView(selection: Item(timestamp: Date()))
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}
```

Item.swift is unchanged from how it was generate in the new project:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

But when I add the parameter in the `#Preview` of DetailView, the compiler won't build the project:

> /var/folders/9j/8r6qn35j5jjf0gm3crp6gynw0000gn/T/swift-generated-sources/@_*swiftmacro_12navSplitView4Item5ModelfMc*.swift:1:1 Type 'Item' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'

What do I need to do to pass these @Model objects around as parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I preview a View that's using @Bindable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77025438/how-do-i-preview-a-view-thats-using-bindable)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the `Item` object you create inside the `#Preview` macro doesn't belong to a `ModelContext` instance which generates the error.

To solve this we first need a separate `ModelContainer` for previews and use that container's model context to insert objects we use in our previews, here is a simple example.

```
#if DEBUG
@MainActor
let previewContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Item.self, ModelConfiguration(inMemory: true))        
        container.mainContext.insert(Item.preview)
        
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create preview container")
    }
}()
#endif
```

where `Item.preview` is a static property defined in `Item`

```
@Model
final class Item {
    // existing code...

    static let preview: Item = {
        Item(timestamp: .now)
    }()
}
```

And then the preview macro is changed to

```
#Preview {
    DetailView(selection: .preview)
}
```

Comment: Except now the preview is crashing all of the time: ```Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018cc95064
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [7271]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
```

Comment: And when I add previewContainer via `.modelContainer(previewContainer)` I get `Compiling failed: main actor-isolated let 'previewContainer' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context`. I believe that this is a bug with Xcode 15 beta 2, as Apple's proejct called `SwiftDataFlashCardSample`, which does this same trick, exhibits the same problem.

Comment: For the second issue use MainAcor.assumeIsolated { … } around the code inside the preview macro.

Comment: I have the same problem, i.e. `#Preview` crashes now with `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)`. How to build preview for views like `DetailView(item: item)`?

Comment: This happens to me also

Comment: @blu-Fox it’s better if you create your own question for this with a well explained example otherwise it’s just guessing.

Comment: After some experimentation just now, it seems we need to create the container first, before adding any objects. Basically follow what PH suggests here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-use-swiftdata-in-swiftui-previews

Answer (score 3):

What helped me as workaround:
Above your preview code, create a wrapper view like this.

```
struct Wrapper: View {
    var body: some View {
        EditingView(item: .previewItem)
    }
}
```

In your preview, just call the Wrapper view and provide a container.

```
#Preview {
  Wrapper()                
  .modelContainer(previewContainer) // Inject preview content
}
```

Comment: That is a feasible solution, and I have used it even before SwiftData to simulate parent views holding \@State variables and passing bindings to the child view, which, in turn, is the view I wanted to develop and test. Inside the wrapper (I call it PreviewCHILDNAMEView), you can use \@Query statements and all other SwiftData magic, ultimately passing the retrieved \@Model object as \@Bindable to your actual View in development. As the .modelContainer is attached to the wrapper call in the preview, it is available with all in-memory down the view tree.