# #Preview crash with @Bindable

Tags: swift, swift-data

When uncomment `TextField("Name:", text: $editedModel.name)` canvas preview crashes with no log...

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    var value: Double?
    var isCheckable: Bool = true
    
    init(name: String, value: Double? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Bindable var editedModel: Item
    @State var temp: String = ""
    private let editModelContext: ModelContext
    
    init(item: Item, container: ModelContainer){
        editModelContext = ModelContext(container)
        editModelContext.autosaveEnabled = false
        editedModel = editModelContext.model(for: item.id) as! Item
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Name:", text: $temp)
//            TextField("Name:", text: $editedModel.name)
            Toggle("Checkable", isOn: $editedModel.isCheckable)
        }
            .onDisappear{
                try! editModelContext.save()
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EditItemView(item: Item(name:"Preview item"), container: try! ModelContainer(for:Item.self))
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by an (old) bug and can either be resolved as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026274/9223839) or another solution is to give name a default value in the model since

```
var name: String = ""
```

but if you don't want to change the model for a Preview/SwiftData bug a third option that is a bit more work but that might be more useful in the long run is to create a specific type to create and hold a ModelContainer instance for all your preview use.

```
final class PreviewSingleton: Sendable {
    static let shared = PreviewSingleton()
    let container: ModelContainer

    private init() {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        container = try! ModelContainer(for: Item.self, configurations: config)

        buildTestData()
    }

    private func buildTestData() {
        let context = ModelContext(container)
        let item = Item(name:"Preview item")
        context.insert(item)
        try? context.save()
    }

    func fetchFirst() -> Item? {
        let context = ModelContext(container)
        return try? context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Item>()).first
    }
}
```

Note that I create a configuration for in-memory use rather and also note that if you want to add more model types the `fetchFirst` and similar fetch functions can easily be made generic.

Then use this singleton (feel free to give it a better name :)) in the preview

```
#Preview {
    if let item = PreviewSingleton.shared.fetchFirst() {
        return EditItemView(item: item, container: PreviewSingleton.shared.container)
    } else {
        return Text("No test data")
    }
}
```